# Press, hide button in ChartContainerContent in UI5 fiori

Tags: sapui5

Hi all SAP UI5 and FIORI positive,

I have ChartContainer with button for graph and button for table. It is defined in xml file as:

```
<suite:ChartContainerContent id="idButtonChart"
                             icon = "sap-icon://bar-chart" 
                             title = "Chart"
                             >  

<suite:ChartContainerContent id="idButtonTable"
                                icon = "sap-icon://table-view"
                                title = "{i18n>table}">
                    <suite:content>
```

[image]

Let's say I want to hide some of these buttons which are placed inside ChartContainer. I have tried (in controller.js part):

```
this.getView().byId("idButtonChart").setVisible(false);
```

or

```
this.getView().byId("idButtonChart").setVisible(false);
```

But this code, hided graph but not button. Please, do you have any idea how to hide button? Or to trigger click event on button idButtonTable?

[image]

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you found any good solution for this issue? I've been checking the SDK and I can't find a way to get those buttons in an straight way.

Anyway, you could do it using the following code -

```
 var chartContainerContent = this.getView().byId('your chart id');
 var chartContainer = chartContainerContent.getParent();
 var aToolbarButtons = chartContainer._oToolBar.getContent();
 var segmentedButton;
 for(var i=0; i<aToolbarButtons.length; i++){
    var button = aToolbarButtons[i];
    if(button.getMetadata()._sClassName === "sap.m.SegmentedButton"){
       segmentedButton = button; 
       break;
    }
 }
 //segmentedButton.getButtons()
```

Once you get the buttons you can setVisible(false) to the one you want.

Of course this is not the best, but the chartContainer doesn't provide any public function to get the buttons of the chart.

Comment: Thank you. It did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand the issue. You define 2 charts in your example.
The buttons are usually used to switch the display to the corresponding chart.

How are you going to switch between the 2 charts if you hide the corresponding button?

Comment: I am using radiobutton for switching between analyses, e.g I have two analyses A and B. For the analyse A I want to be visible both buttons (graph and table) and for the analyse B to be visible just button table. Now I know that I can do this with different chartContainerContent arrays (one with only the table and one with the chart and the table) but I would rather use same chartContainerContent as I am using now. Also would be good to know how to fire event click for for example (idButtonTable). Thanks for trying to understand what I would like to get.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have a good solution for your problem.
The ChartContainer control offers methods getToolbar and setToolbar, but this also doesn’t help much in solving your issue.

Comment: Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I guess an .updateChartContainer() after the .setVisible should do the trick:

```
this.getView().byId("idButtonChart").setVisible(false);
this.getView().byId("<NAME OF THE CONTENT CONTAINER>").updateChartContainer();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not working with this technology anymore. If you are still using UI5 please try to simulate it and if it will be good, I'll be happy to give you vote up.)